# Which is better either creating two objects for two threads or one object for two threads?

Tags: java, multithreading

In the below program, I'm calling method1() of SampleClass from two threads. So, basically I have created  two objects for each thread and called the method1(). I have also seen the scenario of calling static method from two different threads.

Now I want to know what will happen If I use only one object for two threads (I have mentioned in comment) for calling a method(even static method also). I have compiled and but didn't understand any difference.

So, which is better, creating two objects for two threads or one object for two threads?

```
public class MainClass implements Runnable{
    public void run() {    
        try{
            //SampleClass.Method1();
            SampleClass s1 = new SampleClass();
            s1.Method1();
    }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        MainClass m1 = new MainClass();
        Thread t1 = new Thread(m1);
        t1.setName("first");
        t1.start();

        MainClass m2 = new MainClass();
        Thread t2 = new Thread(m2);//Thread t2 = new Thread(m1);
        t2.setName("second");
        t2.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: are you aware of [race conditions](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/231199/are-all-race-conditions-worth-fixing)?

Comment: Which is best, is impossible to answer without knowing what "method1" does. Does it only read? Does it write / alter the state of the object? Does MainClass maintain any state, that is important for later use? The question is not documented enough, to be able to answer it.

Comment: The method1 () simply displays a message. So, In this case which one I have to use or do I need to learn any in-depth concepts In threading to know which one to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, threads and static methods or shared objects do not together easily. There are plenty of techniques for this (worker threads, queues, events, synchronization, etc.).

Using the same instance in two different threads leads to all kinds of problems, just imagine both threads writing to the same memory location (i.e., a member of the object) at the same time. Which thread will "win"? If you call a `method1`, either you must know exactly how `method1` works on the inside (which leads to tight coupling) or you simply cannot know whether it is safe or not (unless the contract of `method1` tells you that it is safe, in which case you would probably not ask the question here).

In general, even (or, rather, especially) experienced programmers will usually stay away from multithreading as long as humanly possible and only use it a) if really necessary and b) in very deliberate ways, i.e., with established patterns like the aforementioned.

Answer (score 0):

Within the context of the current example, you should choose **one MainClass 
 object with two threads** (considering that is feasible from requirements point of view).

For synchronization, you can may have to make modifications in SomeClass.Method1() depending upon the implementation.